# azure durable functions run without a key - how to secure?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-data-factory, azure-durable-functions

We am running azure durable functions from data factory.
We just realized these functions run in a browser without a function key, which is a security risk.

What is the quickest way to secure azure durable functions, but that lets me call them from data factory?

Answer (score 0):

You can add Authentication on existing Azure function its to add on existing function.

Before apply authentication. I can directly access azure function.
[image]

Add Authentication on existing Azure function.

1. Left hand side menu search Authentication.
   [image]
2. After adding Microsoft Authentication i can't directly access azure function. first i give permissions on application then i can access azure function.
   [image]

[image]

Ref. the document to explore more on [Azure Data Factory supports Managed Identity:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-service-identity)

Comment: Thanks, i was hoping to avoid going through authentication, as it adds the complication of trying to authenticate via the azure function task in Azure Data Factory. Any idea why durable functions have a key, but dont use a key?

Comment: managed identity information will also show up when you create linked service, which supports managed identity authentication, like Azure Blob, Azure Data Lake Storage, Azure Key Vault, etc.